# SQL for Next/Prior Business Day from Calendar table (in MS Access)

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I have a Calendar table pulled from  our mainframe DBs and saved as a local Access table. The table has history back to the 1930s (and I know we use back to the 50s in at least one place), resulting in 31k records.  This Calendar table has 3 fields of interest:

Bus_Dt - every day, not just business days. Primary Key
Bus_Day_Ind - indicates if the day was a valid business day for the stock market.
Prir_Bus_Dt - the prior business day.  Contains some errors (about 50), all old.

I have written a query to retrieve the first business day on or after the current calendar day, but it runs supremely slowly.  (5+ minutes)  I have examined the showplan output and see it is being run via an x-join, which between 30k+ record tables gives a solution space (and date comparisons) in the order of nearly 10 million.  However, the actual task is not hard, and could be preformed comfortably by excel in minimal time using a simple sort.

My question is thus, is there any way to fix the poor performance of the query, or is this an inherent failing of SQL?  (DB2 run on the mainframe also is slow, though not crushingly so.  Throwing cycles at the problem and all that.)  Secondarily, if I were to trust prir_bus_dt, can I get there better?  Or restrict the date range (aka, "cheat"), or any other tricks I didn't think of yet?

SQL:

```
SELECT TE2Clndr.BUS_DT AS Cal_Dt  
    , Min(TE2Clndr_1.BUS_DT) AS Next_Bus_Dt  
FROM TE2Clndr  
    , TE2Clndr AS TE2Clndr_1  
WHERE TE2Clndr_1.BUS_DAY_IND="Y" AND  
    TE2Clndr.BUS_DT<=[te2clndr_1].[bus_dt]  
GROUP BY TE2Clndr.BUS_DT;
```

Showplan:

```
Inputs to Query  
Table 'TE2Clndr'  
Table 'TE2Clndr'
End inputs to Query
01) Restrict rows of table TE2Clndr
       by scanning
       testing expression "TE2Clndr_1.BUS_DAY_IND="Y""
       store result in temporary table
02) Inner Join table 'TE2Clndr' to result of '01)'
       using X-Prod join
       then test expression "TE2Clndr.BUS_DT<=[te2clndr_1].[bus_dt]"
03) Group result of '02)'
```

Again, the question is, can this be made better (faster), or is this already as good as it gets?

Comment: Since you have imported the table into Access and the table is unlikely to be refreshed terribly often you could simply add a NEXT_BUS_DT column, populate it using whatever means necessary (even if it is not particularly efficient), and then query the "next business date" values directly. That would also help avoid "query must use an updatable recordset" issues later on.

Comment: This was my default plan to fix the speed before my "cheat" below did the trick.  I try to avoid "make table" type execution when possible because each step is an item that could be forgotten - especially true when it is a step only used once per year.  I also care about the "theory" behind this problem because I sometimes use the same logic up on the DB2 server, where I have no table abilities.  DB2 gets the basic query correct, but sometimes gets confused when it is a subquery within a larger task and produces an abysmal query plan as a result.  (Can't see the plans from DB2, also disabled.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a new query that is much faster for the same job, but it depends on the prir_bus_dt field (which has some errors).  It also isn't great theory since prior business day is not necessarily available on everyone's calendar.  So I don't consider this "the" answer, merely an answer.

New query:

```
SELECT TE2Clndr.BUS_DT as Cal_Dt  
    , Max(TE2Clndr_1.BUS_DT) AS Next_Bus_Dt  
FROM TE2Clndr 
INNER JOIN TE2Clndr AS TE2Clndr_1
    ON TE2Clndr.PRIR_BUS_DT = TE2Clndr_1.PRIR_BUS_DT
GROUP BY TE2Clndr.BUS_DT;
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this approach

```
select min(bus_dt)
from te2Clndr
where bus_dt >= date()
and bus_day_ind = 'Y'
```

[This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-today-s-date-FF6C27E8-8A35-4A15-B053-39FB03778904) is my reference for `date()` representing the current date

Comment: Ah - I think (as normal) I've been a bit unclear.  I intend to use this as a "translation table" to take a list of calendar dates from elsewhere and transform them into their appropriate business dates.  So I am hoping to have a list of, in theory, up to about 30 dates to apply this to, not just the current date.  You have given me the idea though of running the date logic only on those dates I actually require, instead of building the whole translation table, most of which isn't used at any given time.  Query optimizer might even do it for me!

Comment: I imagine a translation query with only two fields: [Calendar_Date] and [Next_Business_Date].  If Calendar_Date is a business day, then the two values are equal.  ("Next" is a bit misleading since it might still be the same day, but I lack a better word for that concept.)  The question title refers to how the same query with reversed signs can be used for prior business day as well as next business day.

Comment: @Et314159 - *"'Next' is a bit misleading since it might still be the same day, but I lack a better word for that concept."* - I'd suggest that you start calling it "Effective business date".

Comment: @GordThompson Effective business date definitely a better name.  It works out we often need to be going back instead of forward, so a coworker suggested "transaction date" (forward) and "reporting date" (backwards) to avoid any (global) ambiguity.  I think this db only uses the transaction date, but the team in general needs both concepts.